# Git backward cherry-pick diff between two commits

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have following commits:

```
repo dev---(222)---v1.0(111)

repo orig---v2.0(333)---
```

***How can I cherry pick diff (reversely) in repo A between commit 111 and 222, then commit result into repo B using git?***

***I have a software repo (dev) with changes (commit 222), but the changes are done on unrelated history to original software repo (orig).***

I did the following (my development repo is "dev", original repo is "orig"):

- added original repo as remote tracking to "dev" repo
- checked out the "orig" repo commit "v1.0(111)"
- committed the changes to "dev" repo

Now I have a reverse diff of my changes: 
`git diff v1.0(111) (222)`

**I would like to cherry-pick those changes and rebase onto v2.0(333) in "orig" repo.**

However I did read in "[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch)", that 
**"cherry-pick A..B" form, A should be older than B.
If they're the wrong order the command will silently fail.**

How is it possible using git?

Answer (score 2):

First, the cherry-pick command would be

```
git checkout 333
git cherry-pick -n v1.0~...222
git commit -m "apply diff between 1.0 and 222"
```

You need to cherry-pick `A...B` between the parent of `v1.0` (since `A` is excluded) and `B`.

Second, since you want only one commit applied to 333 as a result, use the `-n` option.

> This flag applies the changes necessary to cherry-pick each named commit to your working tree and the index, without making any commit.